# Get the smallest value of value in checkbox using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, checkboxlist

I would like to get the smallest value using JavaScript when I had choose more than 10 item. But I couldn't get the result based on my code. I think the error was in "price[i]" but I don't know how to write it correctly.
And here is my code. What is the correct way to get the smallest value?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getprice()
    {
        var total=0.00,i,count=0,min=0;

        for(i=0; i<document.frm1.item.length; i++)
        {
            if(document.frm1.item[i].checked)
                {
                    total=total+parseInt(document.frm1.item[i].value);
                    count=count+1;
                }
        }
        document.getElementById("totalprice").innerHTML="Total Price : RM "+ total.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("totalitem").innerHTML="Total item: "+count;


        if(total>=300 && count>=10)
        {
            for(i=0; i<document.frm1.item.length; i++)
            {
                if(document.frm1.item[i].checked)
                {
                    price[i]=document.frm1.item[i].value;

                    if(price[i]<min)
                        min=price[i];
                }
            }

            document.getElementById("smallestp").innerHTML="Smallest price : RM "+ min.toFixed(2);
        }
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="frm1">

<input type="checkbox" name="item" value="100"/>Pan     RM 100</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="item" value="50"/>Fork     RM 50</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="item" value="200"/>Stove   RM 200</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="item" value="10"/>Pen      RM 10</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="item" value="60"/>Mouse    RM 60</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="item" value="40"/>Keyboard RM 40</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="item" value="30"/>Glue     RM 30</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="item" value="210"/>Speaker RM 210</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="item" value="300"/>Case    RM 300</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="item" value="80"/>Cable    RM 80</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="item" value="110"/>Extention   RM 110</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="item" value="400"/>Redmi   RM400</br>

<p><input type="button" name="subbtn" value="Send" onclick="getprice();"/></p><br/>

<p id="totalprice"></p>
<p id="totalitem"></p>
<p id="newupdatep"></p>
<p id="smallestp"></p>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the problem? And why do you think that `price` exists?

Comment: If all the checkboxes have the same name, how will you tell what was selected? This will send something like `?item=50&item=30&item=300...`.

Comment: The problem is when I run my code, it will not display the result that I want. After I delete the "price[i]" my code then can work.

Comment: I plan to give them same name but using array to different them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your code updated. I change some part to make it easier and clearer.

All the values of the checked checkboxes are stored inside `checkedValues` array

This code is using `Array#filter()`, `Array#map()`, `Array#reduce()` and `math.min.apply`

```js
function getprice() {
  let checkedValues = Array.from(document.frm1.item).filter(i=>i.checked).map(i=>+i.value);

  let total = checkedValues.length === 0 ? 0 : checkedValues.reduce((a, b) =>a+b);
  document.getElementById("totalprice").innerHTML = "Total Price : RM " + total.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("totalitem").innerHTML = "Total item: " + checkedValues.length;

  if (total >= 300 && checkedValues.length >= 10) {
    let min = Math.min.apply(Math, checkedValues);
    document.getElementById("smallestp").innerHTML = "Smallest price : RM " + min.toFixed(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="frm1">

  <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="100" />Pan RM 100<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="50" />Fork RM 50<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="200" />Stove RM 200<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="10" />Pen RM 10<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="60" />Mouse RM 60<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="40" />Keyboard RM 40<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="30" />Glue RM 30<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="210" />Speaker RM 210<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="300" />Case RM 300<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="80" />Cable RM 80<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="110" />Extention RM 110<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="400" />Redmi RM400<br>

  <p><input type="button" name="subbtn" value="Send" onclick="getprice();" /></p><br/>

  <p id="totalprice"></p>
  <p id="totalitem"></p>
  <p id="newupdatep"></p>
  <p id="smallestp"></p>


</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. Some of the code are new to me. I never learnt something like this. I will try to understand it.

Comment: @Beginner Take times to read the documentation of each method. This is not so complicated. If you still have some troubles, you can ask here. Don't forget to thick the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: Okay, I will ask if I don't get it. Thanks!

Comment: Ermm, I don't understand these. 
`let checkedValues = Array.from(document.frm1.item).filter(i=>i.checked).map(i=>+‌​i.value);` 
`let total = checkedValues.length === 0 ? 0 : checkedValues.reduce((a, b) =>a+b);`
What is mean by i.checked?
And what is mean by 0?0?

Comment: @Beginner `i` is one of the checkbox. It will see if the property `checked` is true or false. `filter` will only keep the checked checkboxes. `checkedValues.length === 0 ? 0 : ...` is a ternary operator. if the length of the array is `0` it returns `0` else it returns the result of `reduce()`

Answer (score 1):

I've used `Array#filter` to filter all checked checkboxes, then mapped it with `Array#map` to get value of each checked checkbox. Then - used `Math.min.apply` to get the lowest value.

```js
function getprice() {
  var total = 0.00,
    i, count = 0,
    min = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < document.frm1.item.length; i++) {
    if (document.frm1.item[i].checked) {
      total = total + parseInt(document.frm1.item[i].value);
      count = count + 1;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("totalprice").innerHTML = "Total Price : RM " + total.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("totalitem").innerHTML = "Total item: " + count;
  var checked = document.getElementsByName('item')

  if (total >= 300 && count >= 10) {
    var elems = Array.from(checked).filter(v => v.checked).map(c => Number(c.value));
    var cheapest = Math.min.apply([], elems);
    document.getElementById("smallestp").innerHTML = "Smallest price : RM " + cheapest.toFixed(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="frm1">

  <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="100" />Pan RM 100</br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="50" />Fork RM 50</br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="200" />Stove RM 200</br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="10" />Pen RM 10</br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="60" />Mouse RM 60</br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="40" />Keyboard RM 40</br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="30" />Glue RM 30</br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="210" />Speaker RM 210</br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="300" />Case RM 300</br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="80" />Cable RM 80</br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="110" />Extention RM 110</br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="400" />Redmi RM400</br>

  <p><input type="button" name="subbtn" value="Send" onclick="getprice();" /></p><br/>

  <p id="totalprice"></p>
  <p id="totalitem"></p>
  <p id="newupdatep"></p>
  <p id="smallestp"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: You should try your code first. This is generating an error

Comment: @Weedoze Yeah, I've dropped closing bracket in a wrong place ;)

Comment: @Kinduser No problem :)